# How to update nested json dictionary with multiple values in python

Tags: python

I want to update the below JSON dictionary (jsondict) with multiple values by calling function something like `update_dict()`. Values sent to `update_dict()` are variable no of arguments (sometimes two, three or five). Also, it should be able to update the value for key in a nested dictionary at multiple places. (ex , timeout = '120' in below example)

Function call:

```
update_dict(job_id = "test_1", hostname = "linux" , timeout = "120")
```

Json dictionary:

```
jsondict = {"job_id":"test",
"hostname":"windows",
"username":"user",
"password":"passwd",
"logger_name":"xyz", 
"commands":
        {"command1":
            {"command": "dir",
            "timeout": "60"},

        "command2":
            {"command": "cd",
            "timeout": "60"}},
}
```

How to achieve this using python? Can someone help with this? It will be great help!!

Comment: This is not a "json dictionary". This is simply a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are simply looking for `**kwargs`.

```py
# Don't use; see below
def update_dict(d, **kwargs):
    d.update(kwargs)
```

Of course, phrased like this, the function doesn't really add any value over the straightforward

```py
jsondict.update(job_id='test_1', hostname='linux', timeout='120'})
```

If you want some specific keys to be updated recursively, that might make sense to put in a function.

```py
def update_dict(d, **kwargs):
    for arg, value in kwargs.items():
        if arg in ('timeout', 'hazard', 'snowflake'):
            for k, v in d.items():
                if isinstance(v, dict):
                    update_dict(v, **{arg: value})
                elif k == arg:
                    d.update({arg: value})
        else:
            d.update({arg: value})
```

This marks the three keys `timeout`, `hazard` , and `snowflake` as the ones which will be recursively updated into individual member `dict` objects, instead of being updated in the `dict` itself.

Maybe notice also how

```py
jsondict.update(foo='bar')
```

doesn't let you use a variable to name `foo`, while

```py
name='foo'
jsondict.update({name: 'bar'})
```

provides a mechanism for doing just that.

Perhaps it would even make sense to make a class out of this and provide this as a method of the `jsondict` object. (Overriding the regular `update` method would be nice, but slightly more challenging.)

Comment: As @zvone has pointed out, your `dict` is not particularly a JSON `dict`. I have simply stuck to your nomenclature for the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You can address and update the dictionary directly like so.

```
jsondict['job_id']="test_1"
jsondict['hostname']="linux"

for command in jsondict['commands'].keys():
    jsondict['commands'][command]['timeout']='120'
```

Comment: Hi al76, Thanks for your response. I am looking for something like this. Update should iterate through each key value pair that is passed through function and update it in json dict. In your example ,                                                                 jsondict['commands']['command1']['timeout']="120"                                                                     ['command1']  is not constant. Is there a way that replace timeout key value wherever its present in nested dict and update.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show iterating thru keys.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable comments. Really helpful.